# Binary to Decimal converter works backwards

Tags: python, binary, decimal, converters

I have created a basic program for converting 8-bit binary to decimal, but when I run the program, it works backwards, e.g. if I enter the binary number `'00000001'` the program will return `128`. Here is my code:

```
binaryvalue=input("Please enter your 8 bit binary number.")

binaryvalue=str(binaryvalue)

if len(binaryvalue) <= 8:

    print("Your number is accurate.")
    value_index=0
    total=0
    print("Your number is valid.")
    for i in range(len(binaryvalue)):
        total = total + (int(binaryvalue[value_index])) * 1 * (2**(value_index))
        value_index = value_index+1
    print("Your decimal number is: "+str(total))
```

Comment: Why not reverse the input?

Comment: It has to work the other way- my coursework specifies it.

Comment: Loop over it backwards then?

Comment: I mean reverse the string *after* the user enters it. And if this is coursework, shouldn't you be doing it yourself or talking to your teacher?

Comment: How would I go about doing this?

Comment: It's not official coursework at the moment it's just a mock

Comment: `>>>'hello world'[::-1]` returns `'dlrow olleh'`

Comment: What is your question? If it's "why doesn't it work", it's because you're iterating from high-order bits to low-order. Reverse the loop direction.

Comment: Thanks! Forgot how to reverse a string conveniently :D

Answer (score 1):

So, as mentioned by jonrsharpe and Moe

reverse the input:

```
binaryvalue = str(binaryvalue)[::-1]
```

or, you can place the offset in your power:

```
total = total + (int(binaryvalue[value_index])) * 1 * (2**(len(binaryvalue)-value_index-1))
```

Both are essentially doing the same thing though.